# Nest enum class or not?

Tags: c++, enums, inner-classes

One can have standalone enum-classes:

```
enum class StreamOpenMode
{
    read,
    write,
    readWrite
};

class Stream
{
public:

    Stream(StreamOpenMode openMode)
    //...
};
```

Or nest them in another class:

```
class Stream
{
public:

    enum class OpenMode
    {
        read,
        write,
        readWrite
    };

    Stream(OpenMode openMode)
    //...
};
```

What are the technical reasons to choose one over the other? 
For example, the nested variety can't be forward declared, which might lead to circular dependency issues in large projects.

Comment: Opinion based. IMO if you use `enum class` then it should be outside. Before C++11 internal `enum` was a way to fake `enum class` scope.

Comment: Nore that prior to C++11 scoped enumerations was not available, and the latter approach was commonly used for unscoped enumerations to add scoping by class context.

Comment: I mean it's public so it can be forward declared outside of the class by using the scope operator.

Comment: @BaileyKocin Not if you wanted to forward declare `Stream`, too.

Comment: @Lightning Races In Orbit So you can forward declare it as long as the class definition exists?

Comment: @BaileyKocin https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dcb4ed20033175b7

Comment: @MarekR For what reason do you feel `enum class's` should be outside? The forward declaration thing or anything else?

Comment: @Unimportant It's, well, _unimportant_

Comment: Just convenience: `OpenMode::read` is handy and readable for me and `Stream::OpenMode::read` is already a boiler plate.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's somewhat important to me because I like consistency. I hate doing things one way and then having to do it the other way on occasion because of problems I failed to take into consideration.

Comment: @MarekR The former doesn't tell you what it's the open mode _for_, though.

Comment: Take a look on API he presented and how it will be used, example: `std::make_unique<Stream>(OpenMode::read);` vs `std::make_unique<Stream>(Stream::OpenMode::read);`. Version 1 is much better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> For example, the nested variety can't be forward declared, which might lead to circular dependency issues in large projects.

To be fair, that in itself is probably the strongest technical reason.

You'll also find that Argument-Dependent Lookup relies on the shared scope:

```
namespace N
{
   struct A
   {
      enum class B { aB };
      friend void f(B);
   };
}

void test(N::A::B x)
{
   f(x);  // f found by ADL, since x's type is a member of A
}
```

A different example may demonstrate a whole *suite* of classes similar to `Stream`, each with their own similar-but-different scoped enum. Having it as a member makes it a little easier to use said scoped enum from the context of a template (`T::OpenMode`!). But, in that scenario, member type aliases would make it pretty trivial to keep the scoped enum outside of the class.

Comment: ADL will find friend functions only declared in the class: [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/NEMvve). it can be practical not to polute namespace scope with free functions.

Comment: @Oliv Good shout!